# Overflow:hidden, clear:both and clear fix are not working after using float

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple informative site using html and css and using the 960 grid as the site would have a columned structure.

When I float the header h1 to left (which has the image for the logo, I am adding the image as the background using css) and the navigation list to the right, all the content below it floats up and after using overflow:hidden, its not clearing the floats. 
I have tried the clear fix class of 960 grid and also the clear:both. But they are also not working.

So please tell me what am I doing wrong.

This is the css

```
    /**** =header ****/
header {
    overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 {
    background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 23px;
    width: 174px;
    float: left;
}

/**** =nav ****/

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}

/**** =banner ****/

.banner {
    background: url(../img/city-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:695px;
    height:231px; 
}

.callout {
    background: black;
    height: 231px;
}
```

This is the html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <titel></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960_12_col.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body >
    <div class="container_12">  <!--start container - using the 960 grid-->
        <header>
            <h1>White + Black</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ourservices.html">Our Serices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="howwework.html">How We Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="workexamples.html">Work Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="banner gird_10">
                <p>
                    some text some text some text some text some text
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_2 callout"></div>
        </header>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="grid_5">
                <h3>serices we offer</h3>
                <p>
                    some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
                </p>
                <p>
                    some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
                </p>
                <p><a href="#" class="button">Read More</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid_5">
                <h3>how we work</h3>
                <p>
                    some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
                </p>
                <p>
                    some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
                </p>
                <p><a href="#" class="button">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2">
            <blockquote>
                <p>
                    some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text some text
                </p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p><strong>black + white</strong> themes via <a href="www.themeforest.net">themeforest</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div> <!--end container-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to create a class of `.clear` :

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

And put it after the floated elements. In this case after the `nav` I suppose like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<nav>
    <!-- nav elements -->
</nav>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

But if you have the `.clearfix` class, use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/4/

HTML

```
<div class="container_12">  <!--start container - using the 960 grid-->
    <header>
    <div class="navigation">

        <h1>White + Black</h1>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="ourservices.html">Our Serices</a></li>
                <li><a href="howwework.html">How We Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="workexamples.html">Work Examples</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="banner gird_10">
        <p>
            some text some text some text some text some text
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_2 callout"></div>
</header>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="grid_5">
            <h3>serices we offer</h3>
            <p>
                some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
            </p>
            <p>
                some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
            </p>
            <p><a href="#" class="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_5">
            <h3>how we work</h3>
            <p>
                some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
            </p>
            <p>
                some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
            </p>
            <p><a href="#" class="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text some text
            </p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p><strong>black + white</strong> themes via <a href="www.themeforest.net">themeforest</a></p>
    </footer>
</div> <!--end container-->
```

CSS

```
nav {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}

/**** =banner ****/

.banner {
    background: url(../img/city-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:695px;
    height:231px; 
}

.callout {
    background: black;
    height: 231px;
}

.navigation {
    clear:both;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help, and if this helped you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the markup for your banner container: `<div class="banner gird_10">`

Fix that (to `grid_10`) and your problem should be solved :)